# WP8 app crashes with no exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, crash, windows-phone-8

My application scans a QR code. The user is redirected to another page after scanning. The first time, it works, but when I scan a 2nd time, app crashes and no exception is displayed.

For QR code, I dispose correctly the camera.

```
    PhotoCamera _cam;

    protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_cam != null)
            {
                _cam.CancelFocus();
                _cam.Dispose();
                _cam.Initialized -= cam_Initialized;
                _cam.AutoFocusCompleted -= cam_AutoFocusCompleted;
                viewfinderBrush.SetSource(new CaptureSource());
            }
            base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

After scanning, I change the page of the application with

```
RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/PlaceDetail.xaml?Refresh=true&nbVisit={0}", _nbVisit), UriKind.Relative));
```

And when I arrive on this page, the app crashes after 1-2 sec...

In App.xaml.cs,

I add debug messages in Application_UnhandledException, RootFrame_NavigationFailed, Application_Closing but no message is displayed...

Do you know how I can resolve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I remember correctly UI thread exception can't be catched so that's probably why you don't get the exception message

Comment: Have you any idea to resolve it? From where this UI thread exception could be come?

Comment: It's hard to tell how to resolve this. The exception probably come from graphical component or from a UI.dispatched function if you have any.I don't know if the cam is disposed correctly since i never used that but i would but the .Dispose call as last call on cam

Comment: I use a backgroundworker to load my PlaceDetail page. I just got an unhandeld exception when I load a 2nd time.

System.OutOfMemoryException: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
   at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.NotifyManagedDebuggerOnNativeOOM().

It should know that my page is a panorama and I load 2 webbrowser + a map + some information... Maybe to load this page, it need more memory?

Comment: use the profiler for windows phone that should help you debug the MemoryException. I let you know that I had problem with WebBrowser that caused memory leak but if you just create 2 in the entire app you should be fine

Comment: Thank you. I'll let you know when I find a solution :)

Comment: do You have any success with this problem? looks like I have the same